# How does JavaScript Micro-Templating work?

Tags: javascript

When I go through How [JavaScript Micro-Templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/#postcomment) source code, I am confused about 2 questions:

1. Why use *new Function* rather then define a common function?
2. Why in the *new Function* there is no direct reference to *data* parameter, but can replace with the correct value. I expect to use *data[$1]* to get correct value from data.

The code:

```
(function(){
  var cache = {};

  this.tmpl = function tmpl(str, data){
    // Figure out if we're getting a template, or if we need to
    // load the template - and be sure to cache the result.
    var fn = !/\W/.test(str) ?
      cache[str] = cache[str] ||
        tmpl(document.getElementById(str).innerHTML) :

      // Generate a reusable function that will serve as a template
      // generator (and which will be cached).
      new Function("obj",
        "var p=[],print=function(){p.push.apply(p,arguments);};" +

        // Introduce the data as local variables using with(){}
        "with(obj){p.push('" +

        // Convert the template into pure JavaScript
        str
          .replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, " ")
          .split("<%").join("\t")
          .replace(/((^|%>)[^\t]*)'/g, "$1\r")
          .replace(/\t=(.*?)%>/g, "',$1,'")
          .split("\t").join("');")
          .split("%>").join("p.push('")
          .split("\r").join("\\'")
      + "');}return p.join('');");

    // Provide some basic currying to the user
    return data ? fn( data ) : fn;
  };
})();
```

1. Expect to get statement such as `"<div>",name,"</div>"` then we can use with statement. But String.replace() always returns string. We expect a symbol rather than a string. So in this situation, evel type is best option. This is what I got. Please correct me, if I am wrong.
2. The key to the second question:

   - currying function
   - with statement

Example:

```
function wrapperFn(data) {

    var fn = function anonymous(obj) {
    var p=[],
        print=function(){p.push.apply(p,arguments);};

    with(obj) {
        p.push('   <p>',name,'</p>   ');
    }

    console.log("p.join(''):", p.join(''));

    return p.join('');
    }

    return fn(data);

}
```

Comment: `new Function` is some kind of `eval`, which you will need for these templates.

Comment: `with` is the answer to your 2nd question. It refers to a formal param named `obj`, filled by value of `data` param of the wrapper function.

Comment: Actually He says it in his comments: "support basic currying". He can't do that with out returning a function.

Answer (score 0):

> Why use new Function rather then define a common function?

Because it needs to `eval` the code in the template. With that fancy replaces, it translates that templating language into valid JS statements. Those (still being strings) are then made a function body via [`new Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). For example, the `user_tmpl` example will become

```
function(obj) {
    var p=[],
        print=function(){p.push.apply(p,arguments);};
    with(obj) {
        p.push('  ');
        for ( var i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ) {
            p.push('     <li><a href="',users[i].url,'">',users[i].name,'</a></li>   ');
        }
        p.push('');
    }
    return p.join('');
}
```

> Why in the new Function there is no direct reference to data parameter, but can replace with the correct value. I expect to use data[$1] to get correct value from data.

Because the `data` argument (if present) is passed as the `obj` parameter to the new `fn` function, right in the return clause (last line of code). You then can access its properties (`users`) like variables due to the [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). If the data is not passed, the newly created function will be returned so that instead of

```
 var res = tmpl("templname", data);
```

you also can use

```
 var tmplFn = tmpl("templname");
 var res = templFn(data);
```

This concept is called [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), here wrongly referred to as "currying" (a similar, but quite different concept).

Comment: @IanJiang: What exactly didn't you understand?

Comment: I did't understand why must use evel type function. Finally, I realize that in order to use with statement, we need to use symbol rather string. Since String.replace always returns string.

Comment: Yes, the template code is read as a string, and some parts are replaced to make it valid js. Then, in order to be evaluated, the string needs to become an executable function - what you can do with `var fn = new Function(argnames, bodyCode); fn(argvalues);`. `eval` might have been used as well, but that would need to parse the string on every invocation instead of only once.